# Excel import to SharePoint

Tags: excel, import

I'd like to be able to import a spreadsheet from Excel into SharePoint and be able to select a list template I've already built.  Is this possible?  I need to be able to do this so the proper workflows are attached automatically to the list.  I'll need to create a new list because I'll be getting a different spreadsheet for every order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associate your workflow with a content type.

Extend Mike's suggestion by creating a new list instance which will already have the content type associated with it. As your workflow is associated to the content type you will have the workflow available in the list.

Comment: This is exactly how I envisioned it working.  When I call the web service, I need to supply a TemplateID.  How can I register that Template, so i can use that template during the web service call?  Using Mike's link, I can create an Announcements list by supplying: 104   What number would I use for my custom Template?

Comment: Go to create an instance of your list manually from Site Settings -> Create... You'll see the ListTemplate= in the querystring for the link of your list template. Use that hard coded into your code to create an instance of list with that ID.

If you created your List Template in declaratively through a Feature, you can manually define the TemplateID in the XML.

Comment: I just checked the templateID from the Query String and it's based on the original template I used to build the list.  So in my case, I started with a custom list, modified my list accordingly and attached the workflows.  When going to create a new list from this template, the templateID is 100.  The same as a custom list.

I'm a bit lost as to where to go from here.  How can I take a list template and register it?

Comment: Ah, in that case the template ID is defined when you declaratively (or programmatically) create the list via XML. Are you able to create & deploy a feature which creates your list template?

Comment: I have full control of the farm, but wouldn't know how to create and deploy a feature.  Is this something easy to do or is it overly SharePointesque complex?

Comment: Creating a Feature which deploys a list template isn't terribly difficult - here's a good run-through: http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2009/02/08/A-Quicker-Way-to-Create-Custom-SharePoint-List-Templates.aspx - again, use the 12-hive folder hierarchy in your project and WSPBuilder should make the packaging/deploying a lot simpler.

Comment: Got my work cut out for me, but I need to do this.  It's one of the puzzle pieces in the problem we Skype'd about.  Really appreciate it James.

Comment: Yeah no worries. It really isn't too difficult if you have VS and WSPBuilder, plus learning to do it is an invaluable skill to have in your SharePoint toolbox, particularly when you move to 2010.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're looking for a reusable method that's got some automation.

I'd imagine you could use an Excel macro to call the lists web service, prompt the user to select a template, create that list, then push the data into the list.

You may need to store the list structure CAML in the macro vs. in a template file, as I'm not positive if lists created from a template will inherit workflow (I've never tried that).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.addlist(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Yes, this does get me closer to what I was thinking.  I have the Publish to SharePoint .xlam from Microsoft.  I'm thinking I'm going to have to extend this macro to fire up the web services and create this template.  However, from your link, I have to denote a number representing the template.  If I create my own, I'm not able to call upon that template programatically.  How can I add that as a list I can auto-create?

Answer (score -1):

Create your list using your template and make sure the columns match the excel doc.  Then open the list in the datasheet view and copy and paste the cells from excel into the datasheet view.

Comment: That's not going to be a valid solution considering I have workflows that need to fire upon item creation.  Think of the problematic issues I would encounter if a copy and paste operation failed.  This wouldn't be a viable solution for this.

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand what you are talking about.  You want a list created, with data from excel already in it, and then have the item creation / updates workflow added?

Comment: I'd like to have a table of data in excel imported into SharePoint, not as a custom list, but using a List Template that I've already built.

Comment: Ok, based on that then I stick by my response.  I think you have a timing issue here though.  You want the data in the list but only before your workflows are attached but your workflows are attached when you create the list from your template and you can't add data to a list that doesn't exist yet.  I think your best bet is to write some custom code that allows you to add your excel data and then attach the workflows.

Comment: Not exactly, I'd like for the data to be in the list, but I need the workflows to run for each item that is added from the import.  So, I need to have a List Template w/ Workflows attached to it via content type that fire for every item.  I agree w/ creating custom code but not datasheet mode for the reasons I've said above.  I'm not sure how to register my List Template though.  Do you know how?